# equals() method return false when comparing between a subString and a String array's element

Tags: java, substring, equals

I made a simple code like below and I can't understand why it's false when comparing between a subString and a String array's element.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "abcdef";
    String str1 = str.substring(0, 4);
    String str2 = "abcd";

    String[]arr = new String [10];
    System.out.println(arr [0 ]+ " - " + str1);                 //output: null - abcd
    arr[0] = str1;
    System.out.println("after: " +  arr [0] + " - " + str1);    //output: after: abcd - abcd

    boolean b = str.equals(arr[0]);
    System.out.println(b);                                      //output: false
    System.out.println(str1.equals(str2));                      //output: true

    System.out.println(str1.length() +  " " + str2.length() + " " + arr[0].length()); //output: 4 4 4
}
```

str1, str2, arr[0]: they are same in length and character, but the compare's result is difference. that's weird.
anyone can know about it, pls share.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)

Jave Strings are immutable, substring returns a different string

Comment: You're comparing `abcd` and `abcdef`

Answer (score 2):

Over here, you are comparing:

```
    boolean b = str.equals(arr[0]);
```

but `str` is `abcdef` while `arr[0]` is `str1` which is `abcd`. Hence they are not equal.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean b = str.equals(arr[0]);
```

Did you mean

```
boolean b = str1.equals(arr[0]);
```

or

```
boolean b = str2.equals(arr[0]);
```

Or did you think that

```
String str1 = str.substring(0, 4);
```

modifies `str`?